# Fetch a value from an array in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, perl

Below is my MongoDB collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2a2ee19d332d0118b26dfe"),
    "Name" : "Rock",
    "Job" : [
        {
            "Id" : ObjectId("5b2b93c63629d0271ce366ae"),
            "JobName" : "abc",
            "JobTrack" : [
                "123"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch both `ObjectId` values

```perl
my $cursor = $custColl->find(
    { 'Job.JobName' => "abc", 'Job.JobTrack' => "123" },
    { '_id' => 1, 'Job.Id' => 1 }
);

while ( my $next = $cursor->next ) {

    my $CustomerId = "$next->{_id}";
    my $JobId      = "$next->{'Job.Id'}";

    say "$CustomerId => $JobId\n";
}
```

The result I got from above code as follows

```
5b2a2ee19d332d0118b26dfe =>
```

With this code I'm not able to get `$JobId`.

Comment: Please avoid using HTML in your posts. Stack Overflow uses [*Markdown*](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I am not familiar with Mongo DB, but shouldn't there be an array index in the middle of `Job.JobTrack`? Like `Job.0.JobTrack` or something? Since `Job` is an array of hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the query finds a document, `$next` is a Perl data structure that resembles your original JSON:

```
    {
      'Name' => 'Rock',
      '_id' => bless( {
                        'value' => '5b2a2ee19d332d0118b26dfe'
                      }, 'MongoDB::OID' ),
      'Job' => [
                 {
                   'JobName' => 'abc',
                   'JobTrack' => [
                                   '123'
                                 ],
                   'Id' => bless( {
                                    'value' => '5b2b93c63629d0271ce366ae'
                                  }, 'MongoDB::OID' )
                 }
               ]
    }
```

To get the job ID, you need to dereference that structure using Perl syntax, not MongoDB syntax:

```
my $JobId      = "$next->{Job}[0]{Id}";
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to access a specific element of the `Job` array. Because there is only one element in your example it must have an index of zero. Accordingly you need

```
my $JobId = "$next->{'Job.0.Id'}";
```